# External CSS and JavaScript files not caching?

Tags: javascript, css, caching, browser

All of the sudden (at least so it seems), both Chrome and Firefox behave very strangely when it comes to viewing the source code of a web page. While normally I should be seeing the source like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">"<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Dynamic Map Application - HTML & JavaScript</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/colorbox.css" />
</head>
...
```

I now see it like (copied exactly as the browser shows it to me):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>Dynamic Map Application - HTML & JavaScript</title> <style type="text/css" style="display:none">/**
  * CSS Reset styles 
  */
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td { 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
...
```

As if the style sheets and scripts are not external. 
This is not normal behavior and it did not happen before. And it's affecting how the browser caches external files (i.e. it doesn't).

Can anyone help with this issue?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please explain how you get those sources. For example, in Chrome / Developer Tools / Resources ?

Comment: @MaxArt Right click --> View source

Comment: please provide us a sample html

Comment: Is the result different in Opera/IE?

Comment: @Sagiv I'm not sure what other sample to provide beside the ones above. The first is the source code as I've written it, the second is as the browser displays it...

Comment: @Dmitry Pashkevich The result is identical in IE. I don't have Opera/Safari installed, but considering that the problem is identical for FF, Chrome and IE, I suspect it's the same on others too.

Comment: Well then it looks like the server actually embeds those external files (or maybe it is done by some intermediate proxy). You can try the same thing from a different computer...

Comment: @Dmitry Pashkevich I've just tried on a different computer...not the same problem! This is very weird.

Comment: Check if you have any firewall/accelerating proxy installed on your local machine (or your corporate server), try disabling them.

Comment: @Dmitry Pashkevich Now that you and qwertyboy mentioned it, I am actually using an open wireless connection from a Vodafone store next door. Not usually, just today. And it's only today that I've noticed the problem. Do you think that can have an effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem that was caused by a proxy. Make sure you are not using one, directly or indirectly (perhaps your work place installed one).

Comment: Now that you mention it, I am currently using an open wireless connection from a Vodafone store next door. Not usually, just today. And it's only today that I've noticed the problem. Do you think that can have an effect?

Comment: hey just check it connecting to a network you have control over!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to one right now. That's actually why I've logged in on their wireless network. But I tried on a different computer that's connected to the 'net through broadband connection...not the same problem. And "lucky" for me, I can't use the same connection...